# Getting blank page after publishing my WCF service in IIS8

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, iis-8

I created WCF services and i published it in IIS8 ,but i am getting blank page only.i dont know the reason why it showing blank page its not showing any errors.how to solve this issue.?

I tried following steps what they followed

http://www.kebabshopblues.co.uk/2013/09/20/hosting-a-wcf-service-library-project-in-iis-8-0-windows-8-0-net-4-5/

Comment: What does the access log show?

Comment: I am new to this .where i can see log?i searched in IIS manger but i didnt get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be in hosting and most likely around binding. You may also want to refer to the following link which explains hosting WCF on IIS:

https://jonathanvanderoost.com/2013/11/12/host-a-wcf-service-in-iis-vs2012-framework-4-5/

I am assuming that you would have tested your service in 'WCF test client'. Would also encourage to install SOUP UI from the following link so that you can test the your web service:

https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html

Comment: Now its working Thank u.I changed application pool as a classic.\